# javascript and input, to know when stops writing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a search system, but I dont want a button search, instead, I want when the user stops writing, wait three seconds and perform a search then.

Another approach is every time that user press a key, perform the search, but, this idea is too slow. My data are store in a json file, so, the search consists in two nested forEach. How can I stop the search execution if the user key press again and call search method again?

I'm using angular.

Comment: You could use `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()`...Use `setTimeout()` to start the search maybe 1 sec after they have stopped typing then as soon as they start typing again use `clearTimeout()` then `setTimeout()` again.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code to illustrate what you are thinking thus far?

Comment: searching on keypress is pretty easy, try the "input" event

Comment: I'd avoid the second idea though, if your search function is still executing the keypress will be blocked until it's done ( unless its async )

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

I have input like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { default: 3000, blur: 0 } }">
```

and in controller

```
$scope.$watch('search', function() {
      // this will be called 3000ms after user stops writing
      // or whenever user clicks out of input so it loses focus
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 300ms better than 3sec. Try something like

```
<input ng-keyup="debouncedSubmit()" ng-model="myModel" />
```

And in your controller, inject $timeout and $scope:

```
var timerPromise;
$scope.debouncedSubmit = function(){
   if (timerPromise) {
     $timeout.cancel(timerPromise);
   }
   timerPromise = $timeout(function(){
     // now submit for real
     submit();
   }, 300);
}
```

You could do it more elegantly, using a little bit of functional programming and composing debounce and submit, but I felt like it was outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Perfect! this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use $.debounce method to delay the  execution of search method. In your case something like this.

```
function searchFn(event) {

// Perform an search on $(this).val();

};

$('input:text').keyup( $.debounce( 3000, searchFn) );
```

Comment: This is a jQuery solution, angular is specified here

Comment: my bad! I overlooked angular part.